# change element inner html on class?

Tags: javascript, onclick, this

Here i have code:

```
<div class="starright"><img src="images/stars1.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
<div class="starright"><img src="images/stars1.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
<div class="starright"><img src="images/stars1.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
<div class="starright"><img src="images/stars1.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
```

I want to change onClick image inside, but just on clicked object? Not on all? I have issuse because this is class in css not a ID, is this posible, maybe like onClick This?

Edited. This works great:

```
function change(element){
element.innerHTML = "[new inner HMTL]";
}
```

But how to revert it on first image when second click?

Comment: Excuse me... **what**?? Could you try to rephrase your question to make it more clear?

Comment: I want to change image inside div class "starright" but when i click on just that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in jquery:

```
$('.starright').click(function(){
   var path1 = "insert a path";
   var path2 = "insert another path";
   var src =   $(this).find ('img').attr('src');
   if (src==path1){
      $(this).find ('img').attr('src',path2);
   }
   else{
      $(this).find ('img').attr('src',path1);
   }
});
```

Is what you want?

Comment: That would probably work great _if_ the OP knows to include the jQuery library, and doesn't mind including a library just for this one thing...

Comment: This will change all images, because it is a class?

Comment: No change only the image inside the class that you have clicked

Comment: Txanks this works nice and good, txanks again, is it possible to revert this action on another click, when image is changed i want to click it again and revert to first image?

Comment: you can use an if inside the function to control the src, to view this use this: var src =  $(this).find ('img').attr('src');
if you have solved your question accept it

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that:

Javascript:

```
function change(element){
 element.innerHTML = "[new inner HMTL]";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="starright" onclick="change(this);"><img src="images/stars1.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
```

Comment: Txanks this works nice and good, txanks again, is it possible to revert this action on another click, when image is changed i want to click it again and revert to first image?

Comment: Yes. store the innerHTML first to a variable before deleting. then put it back when you need it.

Comment: How to do that? I have mistakes when i want do that on class and on syntax this, when i have id not a problem :'function toggle2(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
 var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
 var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
 if(ele.style.display == "inline") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
  text.innerHTML = "<img src='images/friendsetting.png' width='13' height='13' />";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "inline";
  text.innerHTML = "<img src='images/friendsettingover.png' width='13' height='20' />";
 }'